# Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination in ng-if

Tags: angular-bootstrap

I've got a [pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.2.5/#/pagination) component wrapped in an ng-if directive. You can see the currentPage updating in the view binding. The controller logs the currentPage each time it's changed, but it doesn't seem to update within the scope of the controller. Is the ng-if directive creating a different scope than the controller? Can someone explain why it's not updating within the pageChanged method in the snippet below?

**Note:** The pagination component works as expected outside of an ng-if directive. I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {

  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
    $log.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
  };
  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.totalItems = 175;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
   
    <hr />
    <h4>Limit the maximum visible buttons</h4>
    <h6><code>rotate</code> defaulted to <code>true</code>:</h6>
    <div ng-if="true">
      <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize" num-pages="numPages" ></uib-pagination>
    
      <pre>Page: {{currentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
    </div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What I understand is that currentPage within the ng-if directive is in a child scope under the controller. Is that child scope completely inaccessible to the parent controller?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, hah

```
$parent.currentPage
```

allows me to access currentpage within the parent scope.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {

  $scope.pageChanged = function() {
    $log.log('currentPage is now: ' + $scope.currentPage);
  };
  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.totalItems = 175;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
   
    <hr />
    <h4>Limit the maximum visible buttons</h4>
    <h6><code>rotate</code> defaulted to <code>true</code>:</h6>
    <div ng-if="true">
      <uib-pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="$parent.currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize" num-pages="numPages" ></uib-pagination>
    
      <pre>Page: {{currentPage}} / {{numPages}}</pre>
    </div>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Had the same problem, but with numPages. I wouldn't bind because of the ng-if (working with ng-show). So I had to write num-pages="$parent.numPages" to be able to access the variable with {{numPages}}

Thanks a lot !